# Laravel Error "Illuminate\Database\QueryException" when run the 'php artisan migrate'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

***I can't run the "php artisan migrate" in laravel project. If I run this command then below error will display.***

Migrating: 2021_08_02_173519_create_access_user

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'access_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `access_user` add constraint `access_user_access_id_foreign` foreign key (`access_id`) references `access` (`id`))

at C:\Users\HETTIARACHCHIGEDAMIT\LanexGloble\lanex-internal-backend\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
694▕             );
695▕         }
696▕     }

1   C:\Users\HETTIARACHCHIGEDAMIT\LanexGloble\lanex-internal-backend\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:485                                                                                      \Database\Conne
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'access_id' doesn't exist in table")                                                                                                        in table")

2   C:\Users\HETTIARACHCHIGEDAMIT\LanexGloble\lanex-internal-backend\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Conne\Database\Connection.php:485
PDOStatement::execute()

**this is an error occurred file.**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAccessUser extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('access_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->foreign('access_id')->references('id')->on('access');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user');
            $table->boolean('status');
            $table->timestamp('updated_at');
            $table->timestamp('created_at');
            $table->string('updated_by');
            $table->string('created_by');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('access_user');
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create the column before configuring it as a foreign key, add `$table->unsignedBigInteger('access_id');` before you define the foreign keys. It looks like you will have to do the same for `user_id` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a column `access_id` before add foreign key on it. The `foreign()` is adding foreign key to **exists** column.

So, you should change migration to below:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('access_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            // add this line
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('access_id');  // depend on your foreign column type

            $table->foreign('access_id')->references('id')->on('access');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user');
            $table->boolean('status');
            $table->timestamp('updated_at');
            $table->timestamp('created_at');
            $table->string('updated_by');
            $table->string('created_by');
        });
    }
```

or use `foreignId()`:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('access_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->foreignId('access_id')->constrained('access');  // change here
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user');
            $table->boolean('status');
            $table->timestamp('updated_at');
            $table->timestamp('created_at');
            $table->string('updated_by');
            $table->string('created_by');
        });
    }
```

See [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints).